# Delete a pointer to C++ list is very very slow. Why?

Tags: c++, performance, list, pointers, delete-operator

I am trying to get rid of an STL list fast. So I have declared a pointer to that list.
I do the all manipulations and then I delete the pointer to free up the RAM.
But the process of deletion the pointer to the list is slow and as slow as when I do list.clear(). So it is very slow. Why does that happen? How can I delete the allocated RAM fast? When I am dealing with vector and deque the deletion is fast. Below is a program which demonstrates that.

```
//============//
// STL delete //
//============//

#include <iostream>     
#include <algorithm>    
#include <vector>       
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::list;
using std::vector;
using std::deque;
using std::fixed;
using std::setprecision;
using std::showpoint;
using std::sort;

// the main program

int main() 
{
  // variables and parameters

  const long int I_MAX = static_cast<long int>(pow(10.0, 7.5));
  const long int K_MAX = static_cast<long int>(pow(10.0, 6.0));
  long int i;
  long int k;
  clock_t t1;
  clock_t t2;
  double tall;

  // set the output

  cout << fixed;
  cout << setprecision(5);
  cout << showpoint;

  // main bench loop

  for (k = 0; k < K_MAX; k++)
  {
    list<double>   * listA  = new list<double>   [1];
    vector<double> * vecA   = new vector<double> [1];
    deque<double>  * deqA   = new deque<double>  [1];

    cout << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------->>> " << k << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // build the vector

    t1 = clock();

    cout << "  1 --> build the vector ..." << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < I_MAX; i++)
    { vecA->push_back(static_cast<double>(cos(i))); }

    t2 = clock();

    tall = (t2-t1)/static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    cout << "  2 --> done with the vector --> " << tall << endl;

    // build the list

    t1 = clock();

    cout << "  3 --> build the list ..." << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < I_MAX; i++)
    { listA->push_back(static_cast<double>(cos(i))); }

    t2 = clock();

    tall = (t2-t1)/static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    cout << "  4 --> done with the list   --> " << tall << endl;

    // build the deque

    t1 = clock();

    cout << "  5 --> build the deque ..." << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < I_MAX; i++)
    { deqA->push_back(static_cast<double>(cos(i))); }

    t2 = clock();

    tall = (t2-t1)/static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    cout << "  6 --> done with the deque  --> " << tall << endl;

    // sort the vector

    t1 = clock();

    cout << "  7 --> sort the vector ..." << endl;

    sort(vecA->begin(), vecA->end());

    t2 = clock();

    tall = (t2-t1)/static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    cout << "  8 --> done with the vector --> " << tall << endl;

    // sort the list

    t1 = clock();

    cout << "  9 --> sort the list ..." << endl;

    listA->sort();

    t2 = clock();

    tall = (t2-t1)/static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    cout << " 10 --> done with the list   --> " << tall << endl;

    // sort the deque

    t1 = clock();

    cout << " 11 --> sort the deque ..." << endl;

    sort(deqA->begin(), deqA->end());

    t2 = clock();

    tall = (t2-t1)/static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    cout << " 12 --> done with the deque  --> " << tall << endl;

    // delete the vector

    t1 = clock();

    cout << " 13 --> delete the vector ..." << endl;

    delete [] vecA;

    t2 = clock();

    tall = (t2-t1)/static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    cout << " 14 --> done with the vector --> " << tall << endl;

    // delete the list

    t1 = clock();

    cout << " 15 --> delete the list ..." << endl;

    delete [] listA;

    t2 = clock();

    tall = (t2-t1)/static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    cout << " 16 --> done with the list   --> " << tall << endl;

    t1 = clock();

    // delete the deque

    cout << " 17 --> delete the deque ..." << endl;

    delete [] deqA;

    t2 = clock();

    tall = (t2-t1)/static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    cout << " 18 --> done with the deque  --> " << tall << endl;
  }

  int sentinel;
  cin >> sentinel; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Each node in a list is in a random place in memory. In a vector, the entire block is in one spot, and that holds pretty well for a deque as well.

Comment: Issues with performance should be accompanied by compiler, compiler version, and optimization settings.  Otherwise we don't know if you're timing an optimized build or not, of if you're using a broken STL implementation for the compiler (which may have since been fixed)

Comment: I encounter the same behaviour under GNU g++ 4.8.1, Intel icpc 14.0 under Linux and GNU g++ 4.8.1, Intel icpc 14.0, VS 2013 under Windows. I am using the -O3 flag. The times I am getting back are the same almost ...

Comment: @paulsepolia: In this case the standard is enough. No need for citing the specific implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Every element in the list has its own node, meaning an extra allocation which has to be freed.

If you want to get rid of it all really fast and use members with trivial destructors (no call needed), use a custom allocator for the list, which is optimized for that.
BTW: Allocating the container on the heap is a pessimisation.

Anyway, depending on your use-case another container like `std::vector` might make sense instead.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to develop a custom allocator.

Comment: The important point is allocating huge blocks, and trying to get rid of it all in one go. If possible, making the deallocation function of the allocator a no-op is a huge speed win. Just hope you don't run out of memory too fast.

Comment: Where else can I allocate the container?

Comment: On the stack, like any normal well-behaved variable.

Comment: On the above program how can I do that?

Comment: Just don't use new? You might want to add some more block scopes for earlier destruction...

Comment: I just tried to use only stack to place the containers. The deallocation (done automatically by the system) is two times faster than when the containers are placed on heap. Many thanks @Deduplicator!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not so much deleting the list, as understanding how a list is represented as a chain of heap-allocated nodes.

So basically when you deleted the list, it also has to delete the ~30M nodes as well, which will absolutely be a noticeably slow operation.

Generally speaking a list is not a great container for small builtin types anyway due to the node overhead possibly taking more space than the data themselves.

Can you give us more information about the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am not trying to solve any particular problem up to now. I am just getting some experience about the behaviour of STL containers under certain operations on them. BTW, I just noticed that if I do not sort the list, but instead if I use it unmodified since I built it then the deletion speed is comparable to that of deque!! So, for sure it has to do with the amount of extra data that has to be deleted (nodes), but there is something else that I am missing ...

Comment: @paulsepolia That sounds like there is some optimization which the implementation is able to perform, which is inhibited by reordering the nodes.